# How to skip checkout and redirect user to payment page directly in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I am looking for an answer about how to implement the following mechanics of payment in woocommerce:

We know the product id, user is logged in, all the user's information is already known, the only one checkout gateway is set up, so there is no need in checkout page. How to skip it?

Well, how the payment should work in my case:

Somewhere in backend the order is generated with all needed information, after this when user click the button "pay the order" he should be redirected directly to payment page without checkout page.

As a result of research I did, the `WC_Order::get_checkout_payment_url()` method was found, but it can give link only to the checkout page, but I need exactly **payment page**, where user can input credentials, i.e. bank card number, CVC. Sure, I can add additional GET parameter to url, for instance 'skip-ckeckout', and on the ckeckout page trigger click on 'pay' button if only this GET parameter in specified. But I think this is not good solution.

I also thought to 'integrate' the ckeckout page contents with **display: none** and automatically fill all inputs where I need to get the payment button. This solution looks weird.

How can I make the described mechanics work without any strange acrions? Which solution is better for me in this situation?

Sorry if the question is stupid, but hours of researches through internet still did not give the desired result

Thank you ❤️!

Answer (score 0):

Got a cool idea for you. I once did this thing where I sent users straight to the payment page, skipping the usual hoops. Let's do something similar, inspired by Amazon's 1-Click Buy Button.

**Here's the plan:**

1. Collect Billing Details: When people sign up or right after, grab their billing info. Maybe toss them a discount or something to sweeten the deal.
2. Profile Page Magic: Add essential billing fields in the user profile. ACF plugin is your friend here.
3. Smart Card Storing: Don’t keep card info on your site. Too risky! Instead, let Stripe turn it into a safe token. You can bill with this token later without revealing the actual card info.
4. Quick Cart to Checkout: When someone adds a product to their cart, shoot them over to the checkout. Fill in their saved info automatically.
5. Stripe Integration: No more old-school checkout. Just use the Stripe token to bill in one click.

**Quick Start:** Grab the Stripe PHP SDK. You can either use Composer or just download and include it in your project. Trust me, it's a piece of cake.

**Tokenize Card Details**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');

// Create a new customer and store their card
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    'email' => $user_email, // Get this from the user's profile
    'source' => $token // This is the tokenized card details from Stripe.js
]);

// Save the customer ID to user's meta
update_user_meta($user_id, 'stripe_customer_id', $customer->id);
```

**One-Click Purchase**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY');

$customer_id = get_user_meta($user_id, 'stripe_customer_id', true);

// Charge the customer
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => $amount, // Convert to cents and get this from the cart total
    'currency' => 'usd', // Your currency
    'customer' => $customer_id, // Use the customer ID saved earlier
]);

// Check if the charge was successful
if($charge->status == 'succeeded') {
    // Redirect to success page
} else {
    // Handle payment error
}
```

I hope this will help.